# Ruby equivalent to Python's DictWriter?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a Ruby script that goes through a CSV, determines some information, and then puts out a resulting CSV file. In Python, I'm able to open both my source file and my results file with DictReader and DictWriter respectively and write rows as dictionaries, where keys are the file header values. It doesn't appear that there is a manageable way to do this in Ruby, but I'm hoping somebody can point me to a better solution than storing all of my result hashes in an array and writing them after the fact.

Comment: FasterCSV gem for Ruby? [Documentation](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/classes/FasterCSV.html) for FasterCSV.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library "CSV" gives rows hash-like behavior when headers are enabled.

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open("file.csv", "wb") do |csv_out|
  CSV.foreach("test.csv", headers: true) do |row|
    row["header2"].upcase!  # hashlike behaviour
    row["new_header"] = 12  # add a new column
    csv_out << row
  end
end
```

(test.csv has a header1, a header2 and some random comma separated string lines.)